# Mongodb project inside array of object with array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB

I have data like:-

```
[
  {
    review: [
      {
        title: "Title1",
        professor: [
          {
            id: "1",
            accept: false
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            accept: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    review: [
      {
        title: "Title2",
        professor: [
          {
            id: "3",
            accept: false
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            accept: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want title and professor array with filter of specific id (like "1")
My code:-
for match i use below code and it works perfectly fine

$match

```
{
      review: {
        $elemMatch: {
          professor: {
            $elemMatch: {
              id: "1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

for project i use below code

$project

```
{
      review: {
        title:1,
        professor:{
          $filter:{
            input: "$review.professor",        (I try only professor but give null)
            as: "professor",
            cond: {$eq:["$$professor.id",  "1" ]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Problem is that professor show array but comes with empty data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HBrE-eRQlwK)

Unwind stage could help you.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      review: {
        $elemMatch: {
          professor: {
            $elemMatch: {
              id: "1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$review"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      review: {
        title: 1,
        professor: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$review.professor",
            as: "professor",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$professor.id",
                "1"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```